# У консоли CLion переносятся сами слова

Tags: c, консоль, clion

У меня в консоли слова иногда переносятся в другую строку. *Soft-wrap* выключен, в настройках тоже, но ничего не помогает. Вот скрин как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: а если запустить приложение с нормальной консоли, проблема воспроизводится? "иногда" - это стабильно, или это случайно-случайно

Comment: @KoVadim С системной консоли все нормально, но можно как-то сделать здесь чтобы нормально работало? Иногда это именно на этой строке. Сколько раз я б не запускал этот код всегда на одной и той самой строке переноситься слово или символ. Зависит от текста. Иногда еще в других строках такое бывает. Зависит от текста

Comment: возможно это глюк clion. У них с терминалом часто такое бывает.